# How can I change the image in the detail view to access the master view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new with iOS development so I was wondering if there is any way to change the image "<" that I got in the detail view in an application Master-Detail for iOS? I'm using Xcode 7 beta and Swift.

Also, is there any way to prevent the master from filling all the screen when I tap to open it?
[Image illustrate the image that I want to customize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXU0V.png)

Comment: Thanks @Brian for edit my question but remember that not all of us are native english speaker, thank you again this corrections could help others to understand better the question

Comment: No problem. Many of the users on this site are not native English speakers. As long as you make the effort to make your question coherent (which you did) then native speakers can edit any parts that might benefit from it.